# Concatenate all combinations of elements between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, out-of-memory, combinations

Let's ets say I have two arrays:

```
$arr1 = array("a","b","c");
$arr2 = array("1","2","3");

function multiply_arrays($arr1,$arr2){
    //what is the best way to do that in terms of speed and memory
    return $arr3;
}
```

What is the best way to combine all combinations of values from both arrays?

The result should be an array with following values:

```
[
    'a1',
    'a2',
    'a3',
    'b1',
    'b2',
    'b3',
    'c1',
    'c2',
    'c3',
]
```

I don't want to face an error like this:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes)
```

Comment: Mathematically it's called a tensor product, but I can't remember the programming term for what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Related: [Efficient PHP algorithm to generate all combinations / permutations of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36612560/2943403) an [How can I generate all unique combinations of multiple array's with optionals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39861500/2943403)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple nested loop?

```
function multiply_arrays(array $arr1, array $arr2) {
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($arr1 as $v1) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $v2) {
      $ret[] = $v1 . $v2;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

I'm assuming based on your example you mean string concatenation. If not, the innermost lines simply varies to the intended result.

Comment: +1 for looking like the solution. this kind of code probably won't hit the memory limit. only if your array is like millions or billions of elements.