# How can I generate all unique combinations of multiple array's with optionals?

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I would like to combine all values in multiple array's to create unique combinations. There is one catch: some array's can be optional.

For example: I'm configuring a PC and I've got the choice between:

- 5 types of chassis (including fans, PSU and main board)
- 5 types of disks (optional)
- 5 types of memory (optional)
- 5 types of video cards (optional)

As you can see the outcome can be any of the combinations:

1. Chassis type 1, Disk type 3, Memory type 5, video card type 1
2. Chassis type 1, Disk type 3, Memory type 5, video card type 2
3. Chassis type 1, Disk type 3, Memory type 5, video card type 3
4. Chassis type 1, no disk, Memory type 5, video card type 2
5. Chassis type 1, no disk, Memory type 5, no video card
6. Chassis type 1, no disk, no memory, no video card
7. etc.

To determine if a range of products is optional, the `'optional' => [0|1]` part has been included in the array :-)

The following array is an extract of an array used in 'production' that should be combined:

```
array(
    array('optional' => 0, 0, 1),
    array('optional' => 0, 3, 4),
    array('optional' => 0, 6, 7, 8),
    array('optional' => 1, 6, 7, 8, 2),
    array('optional' => 1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 9),
    array('optional' => 1, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12)
)
```

The output should be something like:

```
0, 3, 6
0, 3, 7
0, 3, 8
0, 4, 6
0, 4, 7
0, 4, 8
1, 3, 6
1, 3, 7
1, 3, 8
[...]
0, 3, 6, 2  <-- outcome with an optional product from the 4th array
0, 3, 7, 9  <-- outcome with an optional product from the 5th array
0, 3, 8, 12 <-- outcome with an optional product from the 6th array
```

As you can see the array's above are combined into one array. Some of the sub array's are mandatory, where optional = 0, or optional where optional = 1.

Before there were optional array's I've used the following function:

```
<?PHP
function generateCombinations(array $array) {
    foreach (array_pop($array) as $value) {
        if (count($array)) {
            foreach (generateCombinations($array) as $combination) {
                yield array_merge([$value], $combination);
            };
        } else {
            yield [$value];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This was used via:

```
foreach ( generateCombinations($ArrCombinateMe) as $combination ){
    // Some code here
}
```

The function worked perfectly so I would like to use something similar and to be precise I do not want to lose the generator function as it is really memory  friendly (my previous function would combine everything before returning usable output, which could only return 3.2 million combinations at 4GB of memory. This function already passed the 3.2 million during tests in a thousandfold).

Currently I would love to also include the optional array's so that these are also being generated :-)

Please note: I love speed but for this function this doesn't matter that much as it will run as a background job without any user interaction.

I hope someone can help me out :-)

Comment: You want to have a choice to include optional you mean? Beacause if you just want to include optional then there's nothing optional in it.

Comment: That is correct, there is a choice to include an optional product but you don't have to.

For example:
I'm configuring a PC and I've got the choice between 5 types of chassis (including fans, PSU and mainboard), 5 types of disks (optional), 5 types of memory and 5 types of video cards (optional).

As you can see the outcome can be any of the combinations:
`Chassis type 1, Disk type 3, Memory type 5, videocard type 4.
Chassis type 1, no disk, Memory type 5, videocard type 2.
Chassis type 1, no disk, Memory type 5, no videocard.`

Thus the `'optional' => [0|1]` part in the array :-)

Comment: If optional is either 0 or 1 then you can only get all optional combinations or none, so your `[0, 3, 6, 2]` as option from 4th array (only) will never be generated, because you choose also 5th and 6th option. There would be either 3 or 6 elements in result array. You need a way to determine if option was chosen or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) The optional products (memory, video card, etc) are not linked so either one can be optional but the other can also be mandatory. The optional products are set within the admin interface with the "Make optional trigger". We check which products can be combines and which cannot; we then group the products (memory i.e.) and make product group combinations that are compatible. So therefore the `[0, 3, 6, 2]` can be possible. I hope you understand :-)

Comment: So result should be all combinations 3 to 6 fields long (because last 3 are optional) right? Does this data structure can be changed or its already implemented?

Comment: That is correct, the datastructure can be changed because I create the starting array from a database and the output could also to different. Basically all can be changed as everything can be parsed back into the db with some parsing function. The only thing I would not like to be changed is the generator function as it is memory efficient :)

Comment: Ok. One more thing. Why these 3 optional arrays have values repeated from 3rd. Is there some relation between them or is it irrelevant/accidental?

Comment: That is an example mistake, all array's should contain unique id's :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that answer is much more simple than understanding the problem.
You need no change in procedure - just include 'null' as possible value in optional arrays. It would mean that part wasn't included.

This way there will be arrays with null values returned, but their indexes will represent source. Taking array below for example:

```
$data = array(
    'Chassis'   => array(0, 1, 2),
    'Mainboard' => array(3, 4, 5),
    'PSU'       => array(6, 7, 8),
    'Disk'      => array(null, 9, 10),
    'GFX'       => array(null, 11, 12),
    'Memory'    => array(null, 13, 14, 15)
);
```

One of the results would be: `[0,3,6,null,11,null]`* which means that GFX was included.

You could filter that result if you don't want empty values with

```
array_filter($combination, 'is_int')
```

`'is_int'` param is needed only to handle `0` correctly. If `0` is not valid id then you might skip it (and may use `0` instead of null then)

*) actually last element jumps to first position because of `array_merge()` args order

### Edit:

This generator itself is ~35% faster (same memory usage) and doesn't require filtering which overall becomes twice as fast:

```
function generateCombinations(array $array) {
    foreach (array_pop($array) as $id) {
        if (empty($array)) {
            yield isset($id) ? [$id] : [];
            continue;
        }

        foreach (generateCombinations($array) as $combination) {
            if (isset($id)) { $combination[] = $id; }
            yield $combination;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow good find! I've added the null value in the optional arrays and simply adjusted this line in the `generateCombinations()` function: `yield array_merge([$value], $combination);` to become `yield array_filter(array_merge([$value], $combination), 'is_int');`.

I've tested it in a small batch and it worked nicely! :-) thnx!

Comment: @Robbert I've optimized that generator (got rid of slow functions) - see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) I've verified the function with a big dataset resulting in 130 million unique combinations and it is about 2 minutes faster (12 minutes vs 10 minutes).